# Vaadin app not deploying as portlet on liferay

Tags: spring, jpa, liferay, vaadin

Here is the case,
I developed a small Vaadin app(Spring and JPA included with MYSQL DB) and tried to deploy it on local liferay portal.
I used this this [tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+Vaadin+Applications+as+Liferay+Portlets) from liferay to start and then added other stuff.
But something is not working and I can't seem to figure out what, when I try to deploy app on liferay, log says

```
    Plugin package on context VaadinApp cannot be tracked because this WAR does not contain        
a liferay-plugin-package.xml file
```

I tried to figure out what does this mean but investigating on this issue did not give me any conclusion. I have all files in app needed for portlet but not this one.
Is the problem maybe in DBs since liferay uses its own built-in HSQL and VaadinApp uses MYSQL?

This is kind of an urgent matter so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you working with Vaadin 6 or 7?

Comment: I am working with Vaadin 6.  I found out what was the issue, read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
The problem was in DB as I presumed.
Configuration of my DB connection in Vaadin app included a context.xml file with connection to DB configured and that is just the context.xml from Tomcat.
What I did was that I taken the connection configuration from this context.xml and paste it directly to context.xml in Liferay's Tomcat and everything worked.
This is why this Vaadin app worked when deployed on standalone Tomcat server as it was overriding context.xml in Tomcat itself which was not the case when done on Liferay.
Hope I helped someone with similar issue.